# Can I Upgrade My Mid 2009 15 Inch Macbook Pro past it's maximum memory limit to 16gb?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a 15 inch macbook pro (mid 2009 1.8ghz core 2 duo) and I want to upgrade the memory. It currently has 4gb (2x2gb) and the maximum Apples says will work is 8gb. I am wondering if I could get away with 16gb (2x8gb). I know this is possible on certain other macbooks, I am just wondering if it will work on my model.

Comment: According to [everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2009.html), Apple did not make a Macbook Pro in 2009 with a 1.8 GHz processor.

Answer (score 2):

According [EveryMac.com](http://www.everymac.com/actual-maximum-mac-ram/actual-maximum-macbook-pro-ram-capacity.html) no Macbook Pro models build before 2010 had an actual maximum RAM of 16 GB. If your Macbook Pro is a 2009 year model, then your maximum actual RAM should be 8 GB.